# how to display a link in a popup?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a link with the following code.

```
<a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

I want when I click on the facebook link, it should open the window in a popup.
Now it is opening in the same window.

How will I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XHTML Strict:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('fbLink').onclick=function() {
    var w=window.open(this.href,this.getAttribute("rel"),"width=500,height=600");
    return w?false:true
  }
}
```

using

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" rel="external" title="Open Facebook" id="fbLink">facebook</a>
```

---

Safest:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

Possible (here inline):

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"
onclick="var w=window.open(this.href,this.target,'width=500,height=600');
return w?false:true">Facebook</a>
```

---

Onobtrusive:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('fbLink').onclick=function() {
    var w=window.open(this.href,this.target,'width=500,height=600');
    return w?false:true
  }
}
```

using

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" id="fbLink">facebook</a>
```

Comment: Even if this solution is perfectly valid, it is no longer accepted in strict xhtml. This is because this behaviour is not suitable for clients. @Ahmad do you really like popup windows?

Comment: @Aif - what else would you have him do? The OP asked for a popup, so mplungjan gave him a popup.  If you would rather the OP use a lightbox, please post an answer advocating so.

Comment: @mplungjan: the target attribute. I would also add a title saying "opens in a new window".

Comment: @ajax81 (sorry for making 2 comments, but you can only mention one guy): say the OP that it's a bad idea for navigation, accessibility, and user experience.